# Organize Site with Hundreds of Document Libraries?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

I have site that contains 3 sub sites. Each sub site has around 200 libraries. I'm currently using the OOTB Table of Contents web part but even then the lists are long. I'm wondering if anyone has found a better web part that can be used for this purpose. Maybe one with filters and sorting options. I'm interested to hear if anyone else has found good ways around this problem.

Thanks,
Brent

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what version you're on, but in 2013 you could use the new Content by Search Web Part. Configure your query template to restrict contentclass to document library and path to include your top level site url

Comment: I'm on version 2010 Currently. But I really like that idea!